# Web Browser in Oculus Go VR application built with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, oculusgo

I am currently trying to find a way for having a web browser in a VR application. Basically the goal is to open a page like https://stackoverflow.com in a panel and to have it scrollable through the oculus go controller.

I already did some research on plugins for achieving this like [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/embedded-browser-55459) but none of them seems to work on the oculus go.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's nothing out there. I've spent time looking as well. You can make an Android plugin to render a webview if you don't need video. I can post a link to a tutorial if you'd like.

Comment: @palebone would be great!

Comment: This thread has two helpful links for rendering android views to textures via a github project and a tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499396/is-it-possible-to-render-an-android-view-to-an-opengl-fbo-or-texture

Comment: Hey @sebbo I'd love to hear your feedback (including anything frustrating) if you get a chance to use the plugin

Comment: @palebone wir are currently giving it a try. Will contact you regarding feedback next week or the week after :)

Comment: @palebone your solution works pretty well, unfortunately the rather poor performance blocks us from using it in production

Comment: for sure in its current state it's more for prototyping. Currently working on adapting Mozilla's geckoview to replace the webview. The geckoview architecture offers decoupled components that look like it'll allow us to draw the webpage to a texture and display the texture in unity while also allowing video rendering.

Comment: @palebone sounds good, are you planning to release that open source as well?

Comment: Most likely, yes.

Comment: @palebone do your have a rough timing estimation regarding when a more performant version might be ready to use?

Comment: when I'm back with my team next week I'll post an update on the repo.

Comment: target is before end of February though ideally sooner.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the update!

Comment: if we could get this answered we'd have a performant browser soon! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224025/how-to-display-a-texture-in-unity-edited-by-an-android-plugin

Comment: Just spent a bounty!

Comment: @sebbo- you are the man!! Thanks for the support. I may be pretty close to figuring something out, (at least on this one hypothesis) and I'll let you know if I get the answer so you can remove the bounty.

Comment: Given the difficulty of the problem/money we'll have spent on making a performant browser I don't think we're going to open source it. Might be open to a license, lmk if you're interested. Sorry it didn't work out as planned!

Comment: @palebone I can totally understand that. Will text you via email!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I could find, the best solution is [this 3D browser plugin](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/3d-webview-for-android-137030). It's not slow or buggy like the other options I tried and it just works by placing a prefab in your scene that you can click and scroll.

```
void CreateWebView(float width, float height, Vector3 position) {
    var prefab = WebViewPrefab.Instantiate(width, height);
    prefab.transform.position = position;
    prefab.transform.LookAt(Camera.main.transform);
    prefab.Initialized += (sender, args) => prefab.WebView.LoadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

Comment: So far that seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE: I updated the [repo](https://github.com/IanPhilips/UnityAndroidVRBrowser) to support video and is a fully functioning 3D browser based on the GeckoView browser engine. It relies on the `OVROverlay` from Oculus to render frames generated in an Android plugin onto a Unity3D texture.

[This](https://github.com/IanPhilips/UnityAndroidVRBrowser) is a repo I made in the hopes we can implement a nice in-game browser. It's a bit buggy/slow but it works (most of the time).

It uses a Java plugin that renders an Android `WebView` to a `Bitmap` by overriding the view's `Draw` method, converts that to a png and passes it to a unity `RawImage`. There is plenty of work to do so feel free to improve it!

[image]

### How to use it:

At the repo you can find the plugin (`unitylibrary-debug.aar`) you need to import to Assets/Plugins/Android/ and `BrowserView.cs` and `UnityThread.cs` which you can use to convert an Android `WebView` to a texture that Unity's `RawImage` can display. Fill `BrowserView.cs`'s public fields appropriately. Make sure your API level is set to 25 in Unity's player settings.

### Code samples

Here's overriding the `WebView`'s `Draw` method to create the bitmap and PNG, and init-ing the variables you need:

```
public class BitmapWebView extends WebView{

    private void init(){
        stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        array = new ReadData(new byte[]{});
        bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(outputWindowWidth,
             outputWindowHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bmCanvas = new Canvas(bm);
   }


    @Override
    public void draw( Canvas ){
        // draw onto a new canvas  
        super.draw(bmCanvas);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

        array.Buffer = stream.toByteArray();
        UnityBitmapCallback.onFrameUpdate(array,
            bm.getWidth(),
            bm.getHeight(),
            canGoBack,
            canGoForward );
        stream.reset();

    }
}  
// you need this class to communicate properly with unity
public class ReadData {
    public byte[] Buffer;
    public ReadData(byte[] buffer) {
        Buffer=buffer;
    }
}
```

Then we pass the png to a unity `RawImage`. 
Here's the Unity receiving side:

```
// class used for the callback with the texture
class AndroidBitmapPluginCallback : AndroidJavaProxy
{
    public AndroidBitmapPluginCallback() : base("com.unityexport.ian.unitylibrary.PluginInterfaceBitmap") { }
    public BrowserView BrowserView;

    public void onFrameUpdate(AndroidJavaObject jo, int width, int height, bool canGoBack, bool canGoForward)
        {
        AndroidJavaObject bufferObject = jo.Get<AndroidJavaObject>("Buffer");
        byte[] bytes = AndroidJNIHelper.ConvertFromJNIArray<byte[]>(bufferObject.GetRawObject());
        if (bytes == null)
            return;
        if (BrowserView != null)
        {
            UnityThread.executeInUpdate(()=> BrowserView.SetTexture(bytes,width,height,canGoBack,canGoForward));
        }
        else
            Debug.Log("TestAndroidPlugin is not set");

    }
 }


public class BrowserView : MonoBehaviour {
// Browser view needs a RawImage component to display webpages


   void Start () {
        _imageTexture2D = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        _rawImage = gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>();
        _rawImage.texture = _imageTexture2D;

        #if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_ANDROID
        // Get your Java class and create a new instance
        var tempAjc = new AndroidJavaClass("YOUR_LIBRARY.YOUR_CLASS")
        _ajc = tempAjc.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("CreateInstance"); 
        // send the callback object to java to get frame updates
        AndroidBitmapPluginCallback androidPluginCallback = new AndroidBitmapPluginCallback {BrowserView = this};
        _ajc.Call("SetUnityBitmapCallback", androidPluginCallback);
        #endif

    }
   // Android callback to change our browser view texture
    public void SetTexture( byte[] bytes, int width, int height, bool canGoBack, bool canGoForward)
    {

        if (width != _imageTexture2D.width || height != _imageTexture2D.height)
            _imageTexture2D = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);

        _imageTexture2D.LoadImage(bytes);
        _imageTexture2D.Apply();
        _rawImage.texture = _imageTexture2D;
    }
}
```